# assign event at figure that I painted in canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I want assign event at figure that I painted in canvas..

How to assign event?

example - painted 500px - 500px quadrangle and appear explanation if on mouse over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you know your quadrangle position, with and height; you can use the following code to get your mouse position.

```
function onMouseMove(e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
}
```

Finally test if your mouse coordinates fall within your quadrangle,